# Is there a Fannie Mae and Freddie Mac for Canada

Tags: canada, mortgage, security

In the Open Yale Financial Markets Course,   [Prof Schiller](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y_IMH8erqds&list=PL8FB14A2200B87185)

says at 57:40 that Canada Housing Mortgage Corporation is same as Fannie Mae/Freddie Mac.

Are there any differences? Can I buy CHMC shares and bonds just like Fannie Mae/Freddie Mac?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[CMHC's site](http://www.cmhc-schl.gc.ca/en/corp/about/index.cfm) states:

> Established as a government-owned corporation in 1946 to address
>   Canada’s post-war housing shortage, the agency has grown into a major
>   national institution.

There is no mention of this CMHC having done an IPO that would be the requirement for the company to be publicly traded.

---

In terms of bonds, there is an [Investments section](http://www.cmhc-schl.gc.ca/en/hoficlincl/in/invest_003.cfm) where one could learn more about the debt securities the company does offer for investment professionals.

Comment: They may still issue bonds, even if the equity isn't public.